# Formal proof that (x,|x|) is not a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I have perused the related questions on this site, and was unable to find a formal proof of the fact stated in the title. Essentially, I have two questions:

> 1. Is it a fact that if $M$ is a submanifold of $N$, there must exist an embedding of $M$ into $N$?
> 2. If the above is true, how would one show that there is no embedding of $V := \{(x,|x|)\ |\ x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$?

In my attempts, I have been assuming (1) and beginning along the lines of "suppose $u:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is an embedding. Then since $V$ is a one-dimensional manifold (it can be covered by the single chart $(V,(x, |x|) \mapsto x)$), it is homemorphic to $\mathbb{R}$; in particular, we can assume WLOG that a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ is homeomorhpic to a neighbourhood of the origin of $\mathbb{R}$. We can therefore assume that (in a nbhd. of $(0,0)$), $u:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $u(x)=(x,|x|)$ necessarily..." If my proof is right upto here, it is straightforward to then show that the derivative of $u$ vanishes and so it cannot be an embedding. I'm not sure of its correctness though, so I thought I would post here for feedback.

Thanks!

Comment: Everything you said up to "$u(x)=(x,|x|)$" is ok, but that claim is nonsense. Why can't I take, say, $u(x)=(x^3,|x^3|)$ or whatever? Maybe if I was clever enough I could find a smooth immersion with your graph as its image.

Comment: @MikeMiller You're totally right, and the thought occurred to me not one minute after I'd posted. I guess that means that I _really_ don't know how to show this.

Comment: Ultra-vague hint. Think about tangent spaces.

Comment: @MikeMiller I think I've seen the proof that you have in mind. I was just wondering if there was a proof from "first principles", as it were. Intuitively, shouldn't every embedding have to contend with the kink at the origin, i.e. the non-differentiability of $|x|$ at $0$?

Comment: What more first principles that using the tangent space you can imagine?!

Comment: @MikeMiller Apologies! If the idea you mentioned is the answer down below, you're right, that's the fundamental way to do it. The proof that I was thinking about is actually mistaken; I just looked over it again. Thanks for your input!

Comment: No need to apologize. Note that I am not Mariano :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mike Miller appointed, you need to show that there is no $u:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to\mathbb{R}^2$ smooth immersion with $u((-\epsilon,\epsilon))=V$.

To see this, just write $u(t)=(u_1(t),|u_1(t)|)$ and suppose $u(0)=(0,0)$.

The derivative of $|u_1|$ at $t=0$ (which exists because $u$ is smooth) is:

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{|u_1(h)|}{h}.$$

If $h>0$ that number is $|u_1'(0)|$, and if $h<0$ that number  is $-|u_1'(0)|$. Hence $u_1'(0)=0$ and $u'(0)=(0,0)$. Thus $du_{0}=0$ and $u$ can't be immersion.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!