# A nonsmooth manifold example of smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, examples-counterexamples

I'm studying manifolds and I am feeling unconfortable with one definition in particular. The definition is given below:

[image].

Considering this definition, the candidate of manifold I'm using is the set
$$S = \{(x,|x|)\ |\ x\in (0,1)\}$$ with the Topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}^2,$ which is depicted below: [image] This could be considered a smooth manifold because the inverse of $$f: \begin{align}(0,1)& \rightarrow S \\ x& \mapsto (\text{sign}(x)g(x),g(x)) \end{align},$$ where $$g(x) = \left\lbrace \begin{align} &e^{-\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}},& x \not= 0\\ 
&0,& x=0
\end{align}\right.$$ is a chart. Now, to make the atlas $\{f^{-1}\}$ maximal, we just need to enlarge the maximal atlas, as stated by the author.

> What is wrong here? Am I missing something?

Comment: There is nothing wrong since one can give $S$ a structure of smooth manifolds. There should be a duplicate somewhere....  let me check.

Comment: The smooth structure of the manifold comes from the smoothness of the "transition maps" (allowable coordinate changes between two charts, described at point (3)). It's an intrinsic property of the atlas, it has nothing to do with how jagged a given immersion of the manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is.

Comment: You've defined a smooth structure on $S$ so that the inclusion map $\iota:S\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is smooth, but this doesn't make $S$ into a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$. When we define "smooth submanifolds", it's typical to exclude this kind of behavior by requiring that the inclusion map be an *immersion*.

Comment: Related to the above comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1727840/formal-proof-that-x-x-is-not-a-smooth-submanifold-of-mathbbr2).

Comment: It looks that this is a smooth manifold of dimension 1, but it can not be a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Am I right? It looks that studying geometry with pictures can really to confuse someone

Comment: If this is a smooth manifold of dimenstion 1, then Whitney theorem says that It can be embedded in a Variety of dimension 2  Kinda wierd, as well. Can Someone explain It to me?

Comment: The abstract manifold structure is just diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R$, so it embeds any way you want $\Bbb R$ to embed smoothly. The *induced* structure on your picture is not that of a manifold. That's the confusion. And I agree that this is confusing ... after a few years, you'll stop worrying about it :)

Comment: So here is the example where Munkres's definition is different. This subset of the plane has a smooth structure, but it is not coming from its sitting in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Yeas! This differentiable manifold included in some $R^k$ and it is not a submanifold of it. Now I want to understand what the Whitney embedding theorem say about this case.

Comment: @R.W.Prado You need to forget about that non-smooth embedding in $\mathbb R^k$. It has nothing to do with Whitney embedding (which is a completely different smooth embedding into $\mathbb R^m$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing yourself with two different concepts: that of a smooth manifold and a smooth submanifolds.

Consider the map $f: \mathbb R \to S$, $x\mapsto (x, |x|)$ and $g:S\to \mathbb R$, $(x, |x|) \mapsto x$. Both are continuous and are inverse to each other. Thus $S$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$. Since $\mathbb R$ obviously has a smooth structure, the same is true for $S$.

On the other hand, $S$ is [NOT a smooth submanifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1727840/formal-proof-that-x-x-is-not-a-smooth-submanifold-of-mathbbr2) of $\mathbb R^2$. If you don't have the definition of a smooth submanifold yet, then understand this as "there is no smooth structure on $S$ so that the inclusion $\iota :S \to \mathbb R^2$ is smooth and immersed".